# ef core 5 Group By items in list

Tags: c#, .net, list, group-by, entity-framework-core

Hi I want to group a list by items inside an array

```
var localitiesList = localities.Where(x => x.Level == 1).Select(x=>x.Name);



 var doctorsGoupedByLocalities = docs.GroupBy(x => localitiesList).Select(doctor => new {
                    LocalityName = doctor.Key,
                    doctors = _mapperService.Map<IEnumerable<Doctor>, IEnumerable<DoctorDto>>(doctor.Select(x => x))
                });
```

the result by doing it this way

```
   { 
"localityName": [
                "item 1",
                "item2"
            ],
"doctors": [..]

}
```

but what I need as a response is something like this

```
   {[{ 
"localityName": [
                "item 1"  
            ],
"doctors": [..]
},   { 
"localityName": [
                "item 2"  
            ],
"doctors": [..]
}]
```

How can I get a response like that by grouping from items inside an array.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Too much black-box code to answer this. Long shot: move `Where(x => x.Level == 1)` to the `doctorsGoupedByLocalities` query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are grouping by a list base on another list, this is not proper way. you have to group by docs by a property of their own, if you haven't such property you have to create new relation between doctors and localities

Comment: Thank you since it was a many to many relation it worked by grouping the items in the association table LocalityDoctor